# Problem Burning ISO file to disc

Tags: burning

I am using Sony CD-R 700 MB discs and every time I try to burn the ISO file on a disc, an error message pops up saying `error while burning, drive is busy`.

Can anyone assist me in this process? I am trying to do this on my HP touchsmart which has one disc drive.

Comment: provide information of software you are using for it.

Comment: Excuse me i am running Ubuntu 11.10 and the ISO file I am trying to burn is Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Which burning software do you use? Brasero?

Comment: Do you see any pertinent messages near the end of your `/var/log/syslog` file?  I would speculate that your drive is somehow misconfigured -- uses the wrong driver, or somehow conflicts with another device on your system.

Answer (score 2):

You could try burn the iso file in a terminal with:

1. **growisofs**

   1. Install dvd+rw-tools:

      ```
      sudo apt-get install dvd+rw-tools
      ```
   2. Burn iso file:

      ```
      growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd=/path/to/image.iso
      ```
2. **cdrecord**

   1. Add the [CDRTools PPA](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools) and install cdrecord:

      > PPA description
      >
      > > This PPA contains builds of CDRTools and Smake. CDRTools has been packaged as a replacement for CDRKit. This may (or may not) solve many CD/DVD burning issues in Ubuntu.
      > >
      > > The CDRTools package builds Cdrecord, which replaces Wodim, and Mkisofs, which replaces Genisoimage. Add the PPA, update your sources and then install cdrecord and mkisofs.

      ```
      sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools
      sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cdrecord
      ```
   2. Determine dev for CD / DVD burner:

      ```
      cdrecord –scanbus | grep -i cd
      ```

      Output something like this:

      ```
      3,1,0   301) 'Optiarc ' 'DVD RW AD-7173A ' '1-01' Removable CD-ROM
      ```
   3. Burn iso file:

      ```
      cdrecord -v dev=3,1,0 /path/to/image.iso
      ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a USB bootable flash drive?  You can burn an ISO using the command line via wodim.  To install wodin, Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install wodim
> ```
>
> Locate your cdrom drives location with following command:
>
> ```
> wodim --devices
> ```
>
> Command above should give output like the following:
>
> ```
> neostream@ubuntuportal:~/Desktop$ wodim --devices
> wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  0 dev='/dev/sg2' rwrw-- : 'ASUS' 'DRW-2014S1T'
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Using the output from above identify your drive location. In this
>   example it would be `/dev/sg2`, Insert a CD/DVD blank into your CD/DVD
>   burner, then burn ISO image with following command:
>
> ```
> wodim -v dev=/dev/sg2 speed=10 -eject /home/neostream/iso/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
> ```
>
> If you want to burn to CD/DVD-RW disc, you can erase it first with
>   this command:

```
wodim dev=/dev/sg2 blank=fast
```

<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Portal](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/04/quick-tips-how-to-burn-iso-image-via-command-line-with-wodim-in-ubuntu.html)</sup>

Comment: [Many Linux distributions now come with broken variants of cdrtools](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/linux-dist.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your software from the command line and check if it outputs any error. If not maybe you can try using K3b, i find it really good and never had any problems.

Cheers